# GLM - Quaternions and Rotation

Tags: c++, rotation, glm-math

I'm trying to use quaternions in order to rotate objects in my program.

But the problem with them  is applying... a rotation.
I'm trying to rotate the matrix in this way:

```
 ModelMatrix = ModelMatrix * glm::toMat4(glm::quat(RotationW, RotationX, RotationY, RotationZ));
```

with random numbers, and the result is an enormous scaling *(why)* and a little bit of rotation.

Additionally lets say we've got:

```
quat3 = quat2 * quat1
Model1 = Model * glm::toMat4(glm::quat( quat3.w , quat3.x, quat3.y, quat3.z);

Model2 = Model * glm::toMat4(glm::quat( quat1.w , quat1.x, quat1.y, quat1.z);
Model2 = Model2 * glm::toMat4(glm::quat( quat2.w , quat2.x, quat2.y, quat2.z);
```

do Model2 and Model1 have the same rotation?

I know about glm::rotate(Model,RotationAngle, RotationAxis) , but I'd rather use quaternions

Comment: "random numbers" do not a valid rotational quaternion make. The quaternion needs to have a norm of 1 to be a valid rotation, and to convert to a valid rotation matrix.

Comment: u mean I should first normalize the quaternion?

Comment: What does `RotationW` mean? There isn't a W axis in 3-dimensional space.

Comment: It's Just a double representing W variable in the Quaternion (w,x,y,z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a quaternion to represent a pure rotation, it has to be a unit quaternion. Random numbers usually do not have this property. You may want to normalize them before generating the quaternion:

```
l = sqrt(RotationW * RotationW + RotationX * RotationX
         + RotationY * RotationY + RotationZ * RotationZ);
RotationW /= l;
RotationX /= l;
...
```

Of course, it does not make any sense to use quaternions only to convert them to a matrix. Directly calculating the matrix will be more efficient.

For the quaternion product, you have it in the wrong order:

```
q3 = q2 * q1
=> M * mat(q3) = M * mat(q2) * mat(q1)
```

Comment: for the good explanations and the working piece of code for random rotations +1

Comment: Normalization helped times. thank you.
About q product - if I understood you right:
`q3 = q2 * q1;
M2 = M * mat(q2);
M2 = M2 * mat(q1); `// Those need to be done separately in my program. (applied in different time frames)
`=> M * mat(q3) = M2` ?

Comment: and how to "Directly calculate the matrix to be more efficient." ?
Do I have to make a custom function, or does GLM provide such?

Comment: Depends on your parameters. Calculating a random matrix is similar to calculating a random quaternion (i.e. know the degrees of freedom and fill them with random parameters). For a rotation matrix, the column vectors must have unit length and be perpendicular to each other.